# How to add the values according to subject

Tags: python-3.x

**strong text**Let's we have a list :

```
testList1 = [("Sita_English", 1), ("Sita_Maths", 2), ("Ram_English", 3), ("Ram_Maths", 4), ("Shyam_English", 5)]
```

I have added the values by name:

```
out2 = list(map(lambda v:(v[0], sum(map(lambda s: s[1], v[1]))), groupby(testList1, key=lambda x: x[0].split('_')[0])))
```

And i got this as a output:

```
[('Sita', 3), ('Ram', 7), ('Shyam', 5)]
```

**Now i want to have a Output Like:**

```
[('English', 9), ('Maths', 6)]
```

Comment: Just change to the second element of `split`... `x[0].split('_')[1]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo It doesn't work i have already tried it but it doesn't......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

testList1 = [("Sita_English", 1), ("Sita_Maths", 2), ("Ram_English", 3), ("Ram_Maths", 4), ("Shyam_English", 5)]
out = defaultdict(int)
out2 = defaultdict(int)

for i, v in testList1:
    name, lang = i.split("_")
    out2[name] += v
    out[lang] += v

print(out2)   #out2.items() for list of tuples
print(out)    #out.items() for list of tuples
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Sita': 3, 'Ram': 7, 'Shyam': 5})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Maths': 6, 'English': 9})
```

---

As requested by OP

```
out2 = list(map(lambda v:(v[0], sum(map(lambda s: s[1], v[1]))), groupby(sorted(testList1, key=lambda x: x[0].split("_")[1]), key=lambda x: x[0].split('_')[1])))

#-->[('English', 9), ('Maths', 6)]
```

Comment: I want to do this in a functional way